# ASP.NET Core Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

There is a request for the following plan:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Ref(RefModel model)
    {
        var countreward = from c in db.Person
                            join g in db.Referal
                            on c.AccountID equals g.memb___id into gg
                            from ggg in gg.DefaultIfEmpty()

                            where ggg.referal_reward >= 1
                            where c.RCount >= 1


                            orderby c.AccountID == User.Identity.Name

                            select new Person()
                            {
                                AccountID = c.AccountID,
                                Name = c.Name,
                            };
        var reward = countreward.ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (reward.Count >= 1)
            {
                CSData bonus = db.CSData.First(p => p.AccountID == User.Identity.Name);
                bonus.GP+= 10 * reward.Count;

                db.CSData.Update(bonus);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                ViewBag.Message = "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "No";
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

After clicking on the button, I get all the referrals I need from the Referal table, compare their login to the required criteria with the Person table and after that I get + = 10 to my login.
How do I send 5 points to those thanks to which I got 10 points? Thank you!

Comment: You can give 10 points to an account Id, but you don't know how to give 5 points each to a list of account Ids that you already have? What is it you are having problems with? The `foreach` loop? Do you get any error when you try?

Comment: Yes. I already get +10 myself without errors. But I need to give +5 to the person I got +10.

Comment: I need something like: CSData bonus2 = db.CSData.First(p => p.AccountID == reward);
bonus2.GP+= 5;

Comment: Error: The "==" operator can not be applied to an operand of type "string" and "List <Person>"

Comment: Ah, yes. Again, you will need a `foreach` loop and then do what you did to grant the +10 to each element in the list. Can you iterate a list? Could you print the account ids in the list for example?

Comment: Sorry, did not understand (I just started to study). Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` add:

```
foreach(var person in reward)
{
    CSData bonus = db.CSData.First(p => p.AccountID == person.AccountID);
    bonus.GP += 5;

    db.CSData.Update(bonus);
}
```

You should really start studying by reading a book about the basics. You don't do yourself any favors when you get stuck on simple things like iterating a list. Before doing complicated things like accessing databases and communicating over a network, make sure you can do the basics. Learn to walk before you run.